# htaccess redirect if condition Chinese characters

Tags: .htaccess, if-statement, redirect

How can redirect if url contains Chinese characters VS English characters in the same .htaccess file as below:

**Chinese characters :** www.abcdefg.com/wiki/貨船

**Redirect :** [http://www.abcdefg.com/zh/wiki.php?word=貨船](http://www.abcdefg.com/zh/wiki.php?word=%E8%B2%A8%E8%88%B9)

**English characters :** www.abcdefg.com/wiki/Cargo_ship

**Redirect :** http://www.abcdefg.com/en/wiki.php?word=Cargo_ship

Now, I am using the below code, how can I use if condition to join the 2 codes in the same  .htaccess file ?

**Redirect for English:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^abcdefg.com/wiki/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abcdefg.com/en/wiki.php?word=$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Redirect for Chinese:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^abcdefg.com/wiki/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abcdefg.com/zh/wiki.php?word=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Does it is possible to use If Else to RewriteRule ? 
If $ contains English characters
But I do not know how to write if statement. Can anyone help ?
Below is my try out.

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^abcdefg.com/wiki/$ [NC]
<If $ contains English characters>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abcdefg.com/en/wiki.php?word=$1 [L,R=301]
</If>
<Else>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abcdefg.com/zh/wiki.php?word=$1 [L,R=301]
</Else>
```

Comment: How do you differentiate?

Comment: I think he wants to automatically detect Chinese characters in URL. I don't think it's possible but I'm quite interested to know if there's a solution.

Comment: `%{HTTP_HOST} == 'english'"` won't work because you don't have a domain name as `"english"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# handle English URL
RewriteRule ^wiki/([a-z0-9_:'",&-]+)/?$ en/wiki.php?word=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# handle Chinese URL
RewriteRule ^wiki/([^/]+)/?$ zh/wiki.php?word=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Update: With above 2 rules in my htaccess `/wiki/貨船` is served by `/zh/wiki.php` while `/wiki/Cargo_ship` is served by `/en/wiki.php`

Comment: Thank you for your sharing ! It works now. However if the English URL contains 4 special characters, such as : ' " , &  It will redirect to Chinese URL, how to modify the RewriteRule that make sure keep to redirect en/wiki.php?word=$1 ?

Comment: Sorry, one more how to handle A-Z ? the RewriteRule can support only a-z

Comment: such as: abcdefg.com/wiki/AFL-CIO   It will also redirect wrongly to Chinese zh/wiki.php?word=$1

Comment: such as: abcdefg.com/wiki/Single-payer_health_care   It will also redirect wrongly to Chinese zh/wiki.php?word=$1

Comment: It will handle `A-Z` also because I have `NC` (ignore case) flag in the rule above.

Comment: YES, you are right, it support A-Z, but if the URL is  abcdefg.com/wiki/AFL-CIO     abcdefg.com/wiki/Single-payer_health_care    It will also redirect wrongly to Chinese  zh/wiki.php?word=$1

Comment: That's not correct either. Both of these URLs get rewritten to `/en/wiki.php` in my testing.